# Neo4j 2.1.2: Correct way to access long lists of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a list of activity nodes that hang off of the nodes in my graph. The activities are in chronological order so that it is easy to return the most recent `count` activities. The graph looks like the following:

```
 (:node)-[:ACTIVITY]->(:activity)-[:ACTIVITY]->(:activity)...
```

In previous versions like 2.0.1, I could do the following (this is all Cypher over the transactional REST endpoint):

```
MATCH (n:node)-[:ACTIVITY*]->(a:activity)
WITH DISTINCT a SKIP { start } LIMIT { count }
```

Where `start` and `count` were parameters that determined which activities in the list to return. In Neo4j 2.1.2 this now causes the CPU to spike to 100% and hangs Neo4j until you force stop it.  So I tried to put a limit in my query, but anything larger than about 50 will never return.

This query returns 1 activity node:

```
MATCH (n:node)-[:ACTIVITY*0..10]->(a:activity)
RETURN a
```

This query pegs the CPU at 100% and never returns:

```
MATCH (n:node)-[:ACTIVITY*0..100]->(a:activity)
RETURN a
```

Since there is only one activity node, why is the second query never returning? What is the correct way to query a long list of nodes?

Comment: I have a sample database and example queries that demonstrate the failure cases if anybody wants to take a look.

Comment: I think I may have introduced a cycle somewhere in the graph that the query is getting hung up on (though I really can't understand why it is even traversing that path for these particular queries). Unfortunately I can't figure out where exactly it is because every time I try to run a query to figure out what's going on, the query hangs.

Comment: Let me take a look at your sample database.

Comment: Do you have an email address I can mail it to?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j6x-lS8Y946oXwOB7L-_aVjPUjuTE2rw1K2ldOyo7ak/edit?pli=1 join this doc

Comment: I've added some comments to the document. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher is not yet best suited to handling long single relationship lists.

Mark just published a blog post about it:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/07/20/neo4j-2-1-2-finding-where-i-am-in-a-linked-list/

And I experimented a bit with the new cypher query planner and it was much faster.

https://gist.github.com/jexp/4c2601d68d54d8a9c939

can you try to use

`cypher 2.1.experimental` as prefix to your query?

Otherwise it would be a server extension for you,
here is an example to start with:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream

Comment: Thanks Michael. Good to see that Cypher is making progress, but it's crazy how slow it is compared to the Java code. Should I just be writing server extensions for everything I do? Is that what most people are doing currently?

Comment: Also, how stable is the experimental query planner? Should I be using it for all of my queries or would that be a bad idea? I'm seeing pretty good performance improvements on the queries I've tested it on and am thinking about just turning it on for all of them.